# Need to edit a part of 'user profile' page - DRUPAL 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a search in my drupal website which searches for users registered in my website (finder module). Upon clicking any user from the user search result, it takes to that user's profile page.

At the top of that page, a text 'Relationship' is displayed. Under it, a link saying 'become X's friend' (X is the drupal generated name of a user). Now 'X' is the default name generated by drupal when the user registers to the site. Users have their own real name (stored in realname table). So i want to display the link as 'become XYZ's friend' (X's real name). Where should i edit the code?? in which php file??

Example: For a user John Smith, the link will be "become john225de's friend", while I want it to be like "become John Smith's friend".

Answer (score 0):

Are you using heartbeat module for user relations? Once i too faced the same problem, so i used user_relationships  with activity module and solved the problem.